# CATransitions don't work

Tags: objective-c, catransition

I want to ask you a question that is probably very simple but I didn't find the reason for it. I just started iPhone programming. This appears whenever I try to built anything that contain CATransitions.

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I add CoreAnimations to my project I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x68352b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.
```

Do you know how to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Your XIB file, did you hook up view outlet ?

Answer (score 2):

In the groups & folders section can you see QuartzCore.framework? Also, in your "ViewController.h" or .m did you #include ?